# Hover in/out makes my div flicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a flowing-down div. I have the following jQuery code for them:

```
$(".centered-wrapper>main>.event").hoverIntent({
    over: function() {
      var pos = $(this).position();
      $presentationEvent = $(this);
      $fullEvent = $(this).clone();
      $fullEvent.addClass("full");
      $(this).css("visibility", "hidden");

      $fullEvent.css({
        position: "absolute",
        top: pos.top,
        left: pos.left
      });

      $(".centered-wrapper>main").append($fullEvent);
      $fullEvent.find("main").slideDown(50, function() {
        $fullEvent.find("footer").slideDown(50);
      });
      $fullEvent.animate({boxShadow: "0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);"}, 100);

      console.log( $(".centered-wrapper>main>.event.full"));

      $(".centered-wrapper>main>.event.full").on("mouseout", function() {
        $(this).find("main, footer").slideUp(100);
        $(this).remove();
        $presentationEvent.css("visibility", "visible");
      });
    },
    out: function() {}
  });
```

[image: The normal state of the page]
[image: When hovered on the first event]

Everything works well until **I move my cursor up and down on that element**, because, then it flickers and appears and disappears...

```
<div class="event">
  <header>
    <img class="photo" src="/res/users/events-photos/bal.jpg" alt=""/>
    <div class="event-card">
      <div class="date">
        <!-- content -->
      </div>
  </header>
  <main>
    <!-- content -->
  </main>
  <footer>
    <!-- content -->
  </footer>
</div>
```

How can I solve this problem and where am I wrong?

Comment: Could you add it to a fiddle, pretty sure you can get away with just css for this.

Comment: You can't get away with just CSS because I need to position the div to be exactly where the initial one was

Answer (score 0):

You need to **disable multiple queued animations**. The best way to achieve this is to `stop()` it.

**http://api.jquery.com/stop/**

According to documentation:

```
$( "#hoverme-stop-2" ).hover(function() {
  $( this ).find( "img" ).stop( true, true ).fadeOut();
}, function() {
  $( this ).find( "img" ).stop( true, true ).fadeIn();
});
```

In your case:

```
$fullEvent.find("main").stop(true,true).slideDown(50, function() {
  $fullEvent.find("footer").stop(true,true).slideDown(50);
});
```

and:

```
$(this).find("main, footer").stop(true,true).slideUp(100);
```

Comment: it doesn't do nothing

Comment: @Victor show your code in fiddle. Without that nobody will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The visibility hidden code interferes with element hover and causes the flicker. Use another way to hide it. Like

```
.event:hover
{
    opacity: 0;
}
```

To avoid events from firing use  'pointer-events: none;'

```
 .event:hover
{
        opacity: 0;
        pointer-events: none;
}
```